# PINESCRIPT ERROR: mismatched input '=' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

I'm getting this error with this section of script - "line 186: mismatched input '=' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'". I am a novice at this, is anyone able to help/explain the issue? Cheers

```
one_unit = if (highest(lossincrs,lossbars)) = 1
    na(yen_conversion) ? na :round((risk_accountrec/(sl_pips*yen_conversion))/lot_unit*pow(10,round))/pow(10,round)
else
    na(yen_conversion) ? na :round((risk_account/(sl_pips*yen_conversion))/lot_unit*pow(10,round))/pow(10,round)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
one_unit = if (highest(lossincrs,lossbars)) == 1
```

See:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#comparison-operators